# Why would my 15" MacBook Pro suddenly ask me to Hard Quit while I was in a browser?

Tags: firefox, macbook-pro

I was in Firefox looking at a search I had performed in eBay and all of a sudden, the screen grayed out starting from the top down.  In the middle of the screen was a box with about 5 different languages saying I had to hard quit my computer.  I tried other keys on my computer and nothing was working so I hard quit and restarted.  Can anyone tell me why this happened?
Cheers,
Kyle

Answer (score 1):

you experienced a [kernel panic](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1392). these usually happen if you have hardware failing or something has gone wrong with your operating system. in general, i wouldn't worry about unless it happens frequently.

Comment: This is correct. It's extremely rare. If it's occurring regularly, you have a hardware problem, or a misbehaving kext.

Comment: that's good to know. I thought it was infected by a virus or something.  Thanks!